# Changing @click event to occur on page load instead in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some `v-if` props and currently to show divs with `@click="tada = !tada"`.  Instead, I would like the same divs that I'm currently triggering with the @click, to appear when the page finishes loading and occur only once.

I have tried onload, load and other things to know avail.  Thanks for any help

EDIT:

I suspected it had to do with mounted but wasn't sure, so thank you for the hint.

Answer:

```
mounted: function () {
    this.tada = true
  },
```

Comment: After Installation and Introduction, this is explained in the [3rd section](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) of the Vue guide.  It's worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `mounted` lifecycle hook in your main vue instance. This function is called when the component is rendered to the document for the first time. You can read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).